# How to create a view and select from it in one SINGLE query execution

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a veiw and then select from it in one query, would you please tell me how it is possible the code below:

```
create view myView as
select [Order Details].Discount from [Order Details]
select * from myView
```

if i want to run the code, first i have to select that part which is related to creating a view and then i have to select the next part which is related to selecting from that view. i wanted to know the way that both those queries run together when we execute the query the view would be created and then the select executes.

**now i want to add that if once i create that veiw the other time SQL gives me error. how can i fix this?? mean that the object will be created just one time**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just write down Go after the command will work for you

```
create view myView as
select [Order Details].Discount from [Order Details]
Go
select * from myView
Go
```

you can also use CTE if the view is not necessary

```
-- Define the CTE expression name and column list.
WITH Sales_CTE (Discount)
AS
-- Define the CTE query.
(
    select [Order Details].Discount from [Order Details]
)
-- Define the outer query referencing the CTE name.
SELECT *
FROM Sales_CTE
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `exec`for this

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.myView','V') IS NULL
    EXEC ('create view dbo.myView as
    select [Order Details].Discount from [Order Details]
    ')

SELECT * FROM myView
```

Comment: now i want to add that if once i create that veiw the other time SQL gives me error. how can i fix this??
mean that the object will be created just one time

Comment: No mr. Smith unfortuanatly your code does not work and it gives an error pleas help me.

Comment: No the problem is solved, it was a syntax error from my side. thank you.